# R: Create new column by subtracting 2 lines but only if 2 lines in a row have values

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset

In R I have a dataframe from a csv containing different values in column **A**.
I want to create a new column **B** by subtracting the same line in **A** from the next line in **A**, BUT only if there are 2 consecutive values ≠ 0

Best explained by an example:

```
A    B    explanation
_    _    ___________
0    0    0, because A = 0
1    1    2-1
2    1    3-2
3    0    0, because next line in A = 0
0    0    0, because A = 0
4    0    0, because next line in A = 0
0    0    0, because A = 0
3   -1    2-3
...  ...  ...
2    0    0, because it is the last value in the df
```

I did't find any solution for this, because of the different exceptions.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use dplyr to calculate all the values, and also to check if the condition is met.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- 
df %>%
  mutate(
    B = lead(A) - A,
    is_zero = (A == 0) | (lead(A) == 0)
  )
```

Then set any which meet your condition to zero. I think that's a bit faster than using `ifelse`.

```
df$B[df$is_zero] <- 0
```

Gives you:

```
> select(df, -is_zero)
  A  B
1 0  0
2 1  1
3 2  1
4 3  0
5 0  0
6 4  0
7 0  0
8 3 NA
```